# Undefined property: stdClass::$showtitle in custom module

Tags: joomla-3.x, module, templates, custom-module, protostar

I currently have a problem that is driving me crazy.
My module shows the following error in the frontend in the DEV environment:

Undefined property: stdClass::$showtitle
.../joomla3/templates/system/html/modules.php on line 102

And yes when I check $module I see that the parameter showtitle is missing. Now I ask myself the question how I have now probably managed...
Until recently, I assumed that I probably messed up the current update work (just on the way to create an update). So I uninstalled the module, cleared the cache and installed an old version again --> Unsuccessfully. Also with the old version I have now this error... But in parallel everything seems to work on the demo page (where the same version should be installed). All this makes me doubt that the demo installation is on the same level ( even if it should be ).

Does anyone know the above error / can someone give me tips on where to start?
It is effectively that the module title is not displayed in the frontend - no matter what you choose in the backend (which makes sense since the parameter seems to be missing.

PS: The module params are nothing special all joomla standard fields...

Hint:
If I do a var_export of $module within the module (mod_modname.php) the parameter showtitle is present. If I do the var_export inside the System Modules.php file it is missing....

Edit: it looks like a problem that only exists in Protostar, I've changed my template now on my dev system and the problem is gone... thats weird

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was caused by a typo or a mistake that could not be reproduced with the details provided.  These types of questions are not beneficial to future researchers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was that i used the variable $module in my modules template for something else. i had overwritten the original $module, dumb mistake...